# Some programs print errors to stdout instead of stderr, and don't set $? when an error occurs. Why?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh, stdout

See title. I've seen this twice recently, with both `udisks` and `pacmd`, and they are 100 times harder to script because of it. Why do programmers do this?

For example, I want to switch the audio output from a given program (sink input) onto a different output device (sink):

```
$ pacmd move-sink-input $sink_input $sink
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> No sink input found with this index.
>>> $ pacmd move-sink-input $sink_input $sink > /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Perhaps you need [a Magic 8 ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page).

Comment: Haha, maybe so. I just didn't want to rule out that it might be some sort of feature.

Comment: There is no feature or random chance. It all depends on how developers implement their software - that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pactl` is more suitable to run a single command and gives better feedback.

`pacmd` is more for “shell sessions” with the PulseAudio daemon.